# jQuery equivalent of .appendTo() but for .html()

Tags: jquery

I want to change the order of my selectors to match the syntax of `.appendTo()`. For example, there are two ways to append an element to a container...see how the latter approach specifies the container at the end?

```
$('.container').append($('<div />').text('hello'));

$('<div />').text('hello').appendTo('.container');
```

To replace the contents of the container with the element, I have to write something like this:

```
$('.container').html($('<div />').text('hello'));
```

What method can I use in order to specify the container element at the end, so that I don't have so many parenthesis?

Comment: [`.replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) ? `$('.container').replaceWith("<div>hello</div");`

Comment: Why on earth would you care how many parenthesis you have? Worry about readability and how it works instead.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - that removes the container ?

Comment: Oh, I misread. Then just `$(".container").html("<div>hello</div>")`

Comment: I'll save you two parenthesis, so you can just keep doing it the proper way -> `$('.container').html( $('<div />', {'hello'}) );`

Comment: Oooh, I know what to do -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8sNkG/**

Comment: @adeneo yes, that's why I am asking this question...because I'm concerned with the readability of nesting a complex chain of commands within a call to replace the inner html. I'm sure jQuery has a helper method for this...I'm just not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$('.container').text('hello');
```